# List does not exsist

Tags: exception-handling

I have a really strange behavior of a Sharepoint site here

Having a Site and a subweb , everthing works as expected when I use RDP to work with the sites.
But when I remotly access the site , every call to a _layouts recource gives an "List does not exsist" exception.
Even more strange is that this only happens at the subwebs, not the rootweb.
The GUID of the List calls does math, so it should work.
Has anyone seen such a behavior before?

Thanks in Advance

Lars

Answer (score 1):

Ok have found it
Alternative Access mapping was not Configured for the IP

but Strange beaviour anyway .....

Comment: When the AAM is not configured correctly, sp will use the known url internally and "prefix" everything with that. So it won;t be able to find the list